# Dc.js ordinal bar chart gaps

Tags: javascript, html, bar-chart, dc.js

My Bar chart has a gap where half the bar is between the x axis and y axis and I tried fixing this by putting blank data at the start and the end and this makes it so that the bars are not halfway on the axis, but there is still a unruly gap between the Y axis and the X axis. I would either like a way to move the Y axis alone to the right so that it meets the X axis or to find a way to remove the gap without putting blank data. Either Is fine for now.

**Happy Debugging!**

```
function InitPieChart(strings, selectedCity) {
    // cities.forEach(function(city){
    if (selectedCity == "") {
        DataForPieGraph = [{
            Name: "",
            data: 0
        }];
        strings.forEach(function(string) {
            cities.forEach(function(city) {
                DataForPieGraph.push({
                    Name: string,
                    data: (test.SumHelper(Projectsall, city, string))
                });
            })
        })
    }
    DataForPieGraph.push({
        Name: " ",
        data: 0
    });
    console.log(DataForPieGraph);
    var ndx = crossfilter(DataForPieGraph),
        nameDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {
            return d.Name;
        }),
        spendPerName = nameDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {
            return +d.data;
        });

    // CityChart
    //  .width(200).height(176)
    //   .dimension(nameDim)
    //   .group(spendPerName)
    //   .innerRadius(30)

    //   .label(function(d) { return d.data.value})
    //   .legend(dc.legend().x(0).y(0).itemHeight(13).gap(5));
    //   CityChart.render()

    // cities.forEach(function(city){
    ProjectChart
        .width(768)
        .elasticX(true)
        .xAxisPadding(50)
        .centerBar(true)
        // .margins({top: 10, right: 50, bottom: 00, left: -10})
        .height(380)
        .x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(["", "Active", "Pending", "Value.Visits", " "]))
        .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
        .brushOn(false)
        .yAxisLabel('Amount')
        .dimension(nameDim)
        .colors(["#097DBC", "#049FD9", "#C4D6ED"])
        .colorAccessor(function(d, i) {
            return i;
        })
        .xAxisPadding(50)
        // .colors(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(["Active Projects", "Pending Projects","Visits"])
        // .range(["#097DBC","#049FD9","#64BBE3"]))
        // .barPadding(0.1)
        // .outerPadding(0.05)

    .group(spendPerName);
    ProjectChart.render();
    ProjectChart.renderlet(function(chart) {

        var barsData = [];
        var bars = chart.selectAll('.bar').each(function(d) {
            barsData.push(d);
        });

        //Remove old values (if found)
        d3.select(bars[0][0].parentNode).select('#inline-labels').remove();
        //Create group for labels 
        var gLabels = d3.select(bars[0][0].parentNode).append('g').attr('id', 'inline-labels');

        for (var i = bars[0].length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

            var b = bars[0][i];
            //Only create label if bar height is tall enough
            if (+b.getAttribute('height') < 18 && +b.getAttribute('height') != 0) {

                gLabels
                    .append("text")
                    .text(barsData[i].data.value)
                    .attr('x', +b.getAttribute('x') + (b.getAttribute('width') / 2))
                    .attr('y', +b.getAttribute('y') - 1)
                    .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
                    .attr('fill', 'black');
            } else if (+b.getAttribute('height') != 0) {
                gLabels
                    .append("text")
                    .text(barsData[i].data.value)
                    .attr('x', +b.getAttribute('x') + (b.getAttribute('width') / 2))
                    .attr('y', +b.getAttribute('y') + 18)
                    .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
                    .attr('fill', 'black');
            }
        }

    })
}
```

[What the graph looks like when it is displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kLy2.png)

Comment: Have you tried [`xAxisPadding`](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/web/docs/api-latest.md#dc.coordinateGridMixin+xAxisPadding)?

Comment: yes, all that `xAxispadding` gives me is a larger gap and if I make it negative it throws an error.

Comment: I meant, instead of adding the extra bars. You shouldn't have to add extra bars.

Comment: I removed adding the bars and added `xAxispadding` with 0,100,50,1000 values and there was no change. I'll try inspecting the page to see if I'm doing anything wrong.

Comment: I forgot that bar width and padding are entirely different for an ordinal x axis. Please try [`outerPadding`](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/web/docs/api-latest.md#dc.barChart+outerPadding) instead.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! `outerPadding` worked!!!!

Comment: Must clean that up. What a scary mess of special cases our bar charts. Glad it worked!!

Comment: Hey Gordon, now the bars are very close together and .barGap() is giving me this error: `Uncaught TypeError: ProjectChart.barGap is not a function` is barGap no longer a valid function?

Comment: Hmmmmm, there hasn't been a `barGap` in dc.js for [almost 4 years](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/86). You'll want [`barPadding`](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/web/docs/api-latest.md#dc.barChart+barPadding) if you're using `outerPadding`. It's a different system from the old `gap` but we try to maintain both for backward compatibility.

Comment: Hmm, If i use `.barPadding` it says the same thing: `ProjectChart.barPadding is not a function.`

Comment: Are you using the 2.0 beta?

Comment: yeah, I solved the issue, barPadding works now. I spelled my chart name wrong....lol

Comment: Haha that'll do it! Glad it works.